# Сохранить tinymce textarea val что бы отправить аяксом

Tags: jquery, laravel, tinymce

Здравствуйте.
У меня форма отправляется аяксом. Я использую tinymce 4.4.1. Но при отправе на сервер, поле `body` пустое. Гуглением понял что надо у tinymce сохранить данные, но не знаю как.
Вот код

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#form');
        var formData = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url     : form.attr("action"),
            type    : 'patch',
            data    : formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            error :function( errors ) {
                output = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Возникла ошибка</h4><ul>";
                $.each(errors.responseJSON, function(index, error){
                    output += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
                });
                output += "</ul></div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
            },
            success: function(data){
                output = "<div class='alert alert-success'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Готово</h4>";
                output +=  data.success;
                output += "</div>";
                $('#append').html(output);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace('{{ url('panel/article') }}')}, 3500
                );
            }
        })
    });
```

Вот что в массиве
[image: массив отправляющийся на сервер]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения контента из редактора, вы можете использовать метод [getContent](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent)

```
tinymce.editors[n].getContent()
```

Вместо `n` индекс редактора из которого хотите вытащить контент.

Comment: А как сохранить полученный контент в поле?

Comment: `var body = tinymce.editors['body'].getContent();`  отправляю так  `data    :  formData + '&body=' +body,`

Answer (score 0):

Я в итоге нашел такое решение:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
       tinymce.editors[i].save();
  }
```

tinymce v 4.0